Go for a SPL or PPL?
Assuming normal fuel burn and one round trip to the airfield per flight hour, at “C” (Cub J3C) I was told that I “can” obtain a US FAA SPL with 15 hours of dual (\$2,565 @ \$171/h) and 5 hours of solo (\$460 @ \$91/h) plus $1,200. So \$4,160, mixing my math and the school’s quotes.
At “S1” (Cessna C-172) with the same assumptions I “can” get a US FAA PPL with 23 hours of dual* (\$5,618 @ \$244/h) and 17 hours of solo (\$2,754 @ \$162/h), plus \$1,600. So \$9,972.
*Yes, the regs only require 20, but I can only do what a particular school will actually do.
There are other schools that offer C-172s but S1 would be marginally cheaper.
The big difference is the test / prep / checkride. Doing two would be \$2,800, but a year or more apart in time.
Of course there will be fractional overages, and not everybody gets a SPL in 20 hours or a PPL in 40. (Although if you go bang-bang-bang through the course of study without breaks I think you are far more likely to.) But I’m assuming those additional costs are likewise proportional.
Therefore, a SPL will cost me less than half of a PPL. And right now I have no need to go faster or carry more than one person. (It might be hard to find one person who will fly with me anyway.)
Even if I reserve \$1,600 for that second test, the remaining difference (\$9,972 - \$4,160 = \$5,812 - \$1,600 = \$4,212) would buy about 46:15 hours in the Cub. (Plus, as a grad of their school, I’d be able to rent without obtaining an additional tailwheel endorsement or taking a familiarization flight.)
Am I not seeing something? Even if I obtain a PPL in the future the SPL dual hours will count once I have a SPL, and the PiC hours will count as total hours if I go beyond a PPL.
I’m not going to finance flying (even if I could). So it seems like a SPL gets me more logged hours 12 months (and 24 months) from now than a PPL does.

By the way, the "problem" you had with the $ sign is because we use MathJax here as there are often quite complex mathematical notations in questions & answers. MathJax uses the dollar sign. Admittedly kind of annoying when you're trying to post dollar amounts. But the workaround is to "escape" them \$

What you haven't told us is your aspiration for flying? Recreational, Professional, want to get an instrument rating?.... it makes a big difference to the answer.

Jamiec -- Right now, I haven't decided. I am in school right now and cannot decide to borrow a bunch of money to obtain a CPL in the next 12 months. But let's just say that eventually I would want that 250-hour CPL. I can't see how going SPL to CPL by way of a PPL would cost more than going straight PPL to CPL. CPL requires 250 hours, unless I have misread something, all 100 hours of the PiC requirement can be in a LSA, as can all 50 hours of the cross country. Getting a night endorsement on the SPL is illogical if I eventually get a PPL, and I can't do complex or instruments with a SPL.

Jameiec -- thanks $ (backslash dollar sign).

There's some great commentary about this over on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/flying/comments/1e5gxty/spl_this_summer_ppl_later/

Is getting a PPL at the first school an option? You can get your PPL in an LSA aircraft as long as the instructor is a full CFI. Getting your PPL in the cub will be cheaper than either other route.

Chris -- No, one school at one airfield in one direction offers a SPL in J3C's, another two schools offer PPLs in C-172's and one in PA-28s. The least expensive of the latter is marginally further, at a different field in a different direction.

Chris -- Now, there is a place in the next state over that has Cubs 150s and an Archer.

I feel for you guys today. In the early 90s we would get C152s for 38 dollars per hr wet and C172s for 46 dollars per hr wet from Ellington Field or Houston Gulf (no longer there). Self-serve Av gas was less than $1.00/gal as well. Costs today are staggering by comparison. Regardless, I would always recommend a Private Pilot license over Sport. Time and comfort in the cockpit may be the difference between a safe landing or not if things go wrong (like inadvertent flight into IMC at night). Regardless of cost, the additional training for the private is worth every penny.

The average hours of a PPL is around 75 hours. The minimums are a red herring.

I don't know all the nuances of the SPL as it wasn't an option when I got my PPL, but I have looked into it as flying under the SPL rules is an option with a PPL. If you're OK with the limitations, it's a good option.
I think your numbers are fairly accurate, but I would caution that almost no one finishes in the 'published' number of hours. Where I got my PPL, the curriculum was 35 hours (a Part 141 school). I had 50 hours when I took my check ride. Most students had 60-70 hours when they completed. The one-hour lessons, all seemed to take 1.2 to 1.4 hours and sometimes you didn't complete the lesson and had to try again.
In the early phases of flying, flying regularly and often is important to keep the 'momentum'. If you don't fly for two or three weeks, you'll be spending time re-learning the last lesson. I tried to fly every week. I missed a few due to work and weather, but tried to squeeze in another lesson to keep the once a week average. So expect to take more hours than the minimum.
So with all that, I'm in the camp that says flying hours are flying hours and the cheaper the better. With the difference in hourly rates between the Cub and the 172, I'd go with the Cub. And to be honest, it will probably make you a better pilot. Tailwheel aircraft are a lot less forgiving of bad habits.
Yeah, you'll have the added expense of the SPL tests, but if you do go on for the PPL, you're not really out any extra money over the straight to PPL route. I'd do it just for the time in a Cub (I don't have a tailwheel endorsement, but I have flown in a Cub, just not as PIC.)

As of 8.10.24 I have logged about 10.5 hours of dual before my first solo and a few more dual and solo hours thereafter. I see why people say tail draggers are 'hard', although I would just say that they are "unforgiving of inattention, and not really difficult". I'm about $2300 in, and over half-way to . . .. I'll have to draw another distinction here. I may have 100 flight hours logged before I get my SPL if I can afford it [because the weather is great, I'm having a blast, and the DPE is really busy], but I doubt I'll have 20 hours of instruction.
